# Changing values in a varchar column with float conversion

Tags: sql-server

I am working with a table with a column 'value' with the type varchar(100).
All values in that column must be changed by multiplying them with 0.001 but my following update script fails due to "arithmetical overflow error  while converting varchar to a numeric type".

```
update testTable
  set value = cast ((value * 0.001) as varchar);
```

I must not change the type of the column and it holds values between 0 and 4294966796.

How do i cast correctly to get the calculation in the update working?

I tried `cast (cast ((value * 0.001)) as float) as varchar)` but it still throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CAST(CAST( value AS NUMERIC) *0.001 AS VARCHAR(100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here try this :

```
update testTable
  set value = cast ((cast(value as float) * 0.001) as varchar);
```

If it still fails then one of the rows have non-numeric value

Answer (score 1):

You can;

```
update testTable cast(cast(value as decimal) * 0.001 as varchar(32))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
update testTable
  set value = convert(float,value) * 0.001
```

A simple example you can run

```
DECLARE @z varchar(100)
SELECT @z = CONVERT(float,'123') * 0.001

SELECT @z
```

0.123

Answer (score 0):

If your values exceed the size of a float, then you can do the arithmetic as strings.  This is a special case, because multiplying by `0.001` is just moving the decimal place over three places to the left.  The following works for values greater than 1000, with or without decimal places:

```
update testTable
    set value = (case when charindex('.', value) = 0
                      then left(value, len(value) - 3)+'.'+right(value, 3)
                      else left(value, charidnex('.', value) - 3) + '.' +
                           replace(right(value, len(value) - charindex('.', value) + 4), '.', '')
                 end)
```

If you have values less than 100, then you will need to prepend the values with 0s for this to work.